# CheckBoxList problemas con mi Store Procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net

Mi problema es el siguiente tengo checkboxList
quiero recorrerlo y los valores seleccionados tomarlos para mi store procedure.
Este codigo solo me toma un elemento, al momento que se selecciona 2 no me trae el datagridview

Les dejo mi codigo (store procedure y del visual)

DESDE YA MUCHAS GRACIAS

VISUAL

```
protected void cargarDatos()
    {

        int aux = 0;

        DataTable dtDatos = null;

        string strConsulta = "exec SP_Mostrar_ListaDeCuentasDeterminadas";

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFechaDesde.Text))
        {
            if (aux == 1)
            {
                strConsulta = strConsulta + ", @fechaDesde = '" + txtFechaDesde.Text + "'";
            }
            else
            {
                strConsulta = strConsulta + " @fechaDesde = '" + txtFechaDesde.Text + "'";
                aux = 1;
            }
        }
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFechaHasta.Text))
        {
            if (aux == 1)
            {
                strConsulta = strConsulta + ", @fechaHasta = '" + txtFechaHasta.Text + "'";
            }
            else
            {
                strConsulta = strConsulta + " @fechaHasta = '" + txtFechaHasta.Text + "'";
                aux = 1;
            }
        }

        if (cboComprobantes.SelectedItem.Value != "Seleccione")
        {
            if (aux == 1)
            {
                strConsulta = strConsulta + ", @comprobante = " + cboComprobantes.SelectedItem.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                strConsulta = strConsulta + " @comprobante = " + cboComprobantes.SelectedItem.Value;
                aux = 1;
            }
        }            


        for (int i = 0; i < chkCuentas.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (chkCuentas.Items[i].Selected)
            {

                    if (aux == 1)
                    {
                        strConsulta = strConsulta + ", @cuenta = " + chkCuentas.Items[i].Value;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        strConsulta = strConsulta + " @cuenta = " + chkCuentas.Items[i].Value;
                        aux = 1;
                    }

            }
        }


        dtDatos = Conexion.llenarGridFromConsulta(strConsulta);

        grDatos.DataSource = dtDatos;
        grDatos.DataBind();
        btnExcel.Visible = true;
    }
```

STORE PROCEDURE

```
declare @consulta varchar(3000)
set @consulta = N' select TransaccionId, AccountCode, Cuentas.Description, NetAmount, CreatedDate, DocumentType, '
set @consulta = @consulta + ' DateName( day , EffectiveDate) + ' + '''  ''' + ' + DateName(  month , EffectiveDate) + ' + '''  ''' + ' + DateName(  year , EffectiveDate) as fecha, '
set @consulta = @consulta + ' JournalDescription, LineDescription, nombreApellido_usuario, cargo, Movimiento.Descripcion, TiposComprobante.codigo_comprobante '
set @consulta = @consulta + ' from TablaPrincipal '
set @consulta = @consulta + ' left join Cuentas on TablaPrincipal.AccountCode = Cuentas.id_cuenta '
set @consulta = @consulta + ' left join Usuarios on TablaPrincipal.UserId = Usuarios.Id_usuario '
set @consulta = @consulta + ' left join Movimiento on TablaPrincipal.Id_movimiento = Movimiento.Id_movimiento '
set @consulta = @consulta + ' left join TiposComprobante on TablaPrincipal.TipoComprobante = TiposComprobante.id_comprobante '

declare @aux int
set @aux = 0

    if @fechaDesde is not null 
    begin
        if @aux = 1
            begin
                set @consulta = @consulta + ' and CreatedDate >=  ''' +  CAST ( @fechaDesde as  varchar (12) ) + ''''

            end
        else
            begin
                set @aux = 1 
                set @consulta = @consulta + ' where CreatedDate >=   ''' +  CAST ( @fechaDesde as  varchar (12) )+ ''''
            end
    end 


    if @fechaHasta is not null 
    begin
        if @aux = 1
            begin
                set @consulta = @consulta + ' and CreatedDate <=  ''' +  CAST ( @fechaHasta as  varchar (12) )+ ''''

            end
        else
            begin
                set @aux = 1 
                set @consulta = @consulta + ' where CreatedDate <=  ''' +  CAST ( @fechaHasta as  varchar (12) )+ ''''
            end
    end 

         if @comprobante is not null 
    begin
        if @aux = 1
            begin
                set @consulta = @consulta + ' and TipoComprobante   =  ' +  CAST ( @comprobante as  varchar (8) )

            end
        else
            begin
                set @aux = 1 
                set @consulta = @consulta + ' where TipoComprobante  = ' +  CAST ( @comprobante as  varchar (8) )
            end
    end

         if @cuenta is not null 
    begin
        if @aux = 1
            begin
                set @consulta = @consulta + ' and AccountCode   =  ' +  CAST ( @cuenta as  varchar (8) )


            end
        else
            begin
                set @aux = 1 
                set @consulta = @consulta + ' where AccountCode  = ' +  CAST ( @cuenta as  varchar (8) )


            end
    end
```

Answer (score 2):

El error es de concepto y esta en el SP...

Si vos escribis un where de la siguiente forma:

```
Where AccountCode = 1 and AccountCode = 2 and AccountCode = 3
```

ningun registro cumple con esa condición.

La base de datos procesa y revisa los registros uno a uno, y de esta forma esta buscando en cada fila, que el AccountCode sea igual a 1 y a 2 y a 3 al mismo tiempo, cosa que es imposible.

Lo que a vos te tiene que quedar, es algo asi:

```
Where AccountCode in (1,2,3)
```

Porque la clausula in, es como un or.

Otra solución mas fea seria usar el or

```
Where ...otras clausulas... and (AccountCode = 1 or AccountCode = 2 or AccountCode = 3)
```